# What are alternate uses for leftover buttermilk?

Tags: baking, bread, buttermilk

Buttermilk is one of those pantry items that I buy for a specific recipe, then don't know what to do with the leftovers (and I think this is not uncommon).  In my question about [buttermilk in soda bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13257/why-does-soda-bread-call-for-buttermilk), the topic of alternate uses came up in the comments.  I'd like to make a list of these uses.  Here's what I have so far:

- pancakes (instead of milk or yogourt)
- quick breads, scones (instead of milk)
- cakes
- mashed potatoes (instead of milk)
- low-fat muffins (replacement for oil)

(Note: This should be a community wiki item, rather than a question, but I'm not sure how to flag that.)

Comment: @Allison - I don't think this fits our [culinary uses guidelines](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/740/can-i-ask-about-how-to-use-a-specific-ingredient-aka-culinary-uses-guidelines), which is what it would have to be tagged.  Voted to close.  You can try to edit to see if you can get it there, but buttermilk's a bit too common for that.

Comment: @justkt - fair enough.  For me it falls into the category of "Things which have a specific (or few) widely recognised uses which may have other uncommon uses." I associate buttermilk mostly with pancakes and muffins, but haven't used it for anything else (most of my list came from your comment in the other question).

Comment: [25 uses](http://www.soundmoneymatters.com/uses-for-buttermilk/) is not a few.  And that's just one website's list off google.  Others may of course disagree, though!

Comment: For me the key phrase was "widely recognized" ... but I guess I don't need a list here, since I can now refer to the one you linked to! :)

Comment: I used to do buy buttermilk for specific recipes and then have leftovers but now if the recipe calls for a small amount (1-3 cups) I just use a buttermilk substitute by mixing milk with vinegar and letting it sit for ten minutes.

Comment: @justkt and Allison, Check out the new question on meta about where the boundary for these types of questions lies. http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-culinary-uses-questions

Comment: @yossarian -  Thanks for raising this... I think it's a tricky subjective line.  And for reference, looking at that list more closely, it's not really 25 things, in my opinion. A lot of the items I would group together (e.g. biscuits and scones are basically the same thing, as are various kinds of cakes).  Also, another interesting use I'd add to a list is as a beverage when mixed with OJ, which is a traditional Dutch lunch drink.

Comment: I realize this is closed, but I had an answer that's not a "list entry" but a more general solution.  Since I also tend to purchase buttermilk for specific purposes, and get frustrated with 1/4 cups going to waste, I tend to stretch recipes to fit the amount of buttermilk I can buy.  Add 1/7th to all the other ingredients, or just be happy adding a bit of extra buttermilk to the item.  Makes slightly larger batches, slightly richer foods, and no wasted buttermilk.

Comment: The most obvious - drink it! Have hot mushed potato on a plate, some meat next to it and cold buttermilk in a glass. Yum.